# How to make chrome open in backgroung using selenium in nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I'm not finding it so help me.

```
const {Builder, By, Key, Until} = require ('selenium-webdriver');
let driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
let monedha=[];
let bitToUsd=0;
async function prov(){
    await driver.get('https://coinmarketcap.com');
    let links = await driver.findElements({css:'.price'});

    for (let i=0;i<links.length;i++){
        text = await links[i].getText();
        monedha.push(text);
    }
```

returnun value  that is saved in array

```
    bitToUsd=monedha[0];
    console.log(bitToUsd);
    return driver.quit();
}
prov();
```

Answer (score 0):

i found it here it is hope it will halp u:

```
const express=require('express')
const bodyParser=require('body-parser')

let app=express();

app.get('/prj',(req,res)=>{
const webdriver=require('selenium-webdriver')
const chrome=require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')
var o=new chrome.Options();
o.addArguments('disable-infobars');
o.addArguments("headless")


let monedhausd=[];
let bitcoinToUsd=0;
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().setChromeOptions(o).forBrowser('chrome').build();
(async function best ()
{
await driver.get('https://coinmarketcap.com');
let links=await driver.findElements({css:'.price'});
for(let i=0;i<links.length;i++){

text =await links[i].getText()
monedhausd.push(text)
}
bitcoinToUsd=monedhausd[0];
console.log(bitcoinToUsd);
res.status(400).json({message:'vlera ne bitcoin eshte',
data:bitcoinToUsd   
})
return driver.quit()
}
)
()

})

app.listen('5000',()=>{
console.log('serveri is on')
})
```